# R export to SAS using foreign: why do boolean fields cause "Invalid data for ..." error?

Tags: r, import, export, boolean, sas

I suspect this is a bug in library(foreign) but I am not sure.

When I export a dataframe containing a boolean vector with write.foreign, the resulting SASDATA file causes an error on SAS import.

Example:

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), boolean = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))
library(foreign)
write.foreign(df, "test.sasdata", "test.sas",
    "SAS", dataname="WORK.TEST", validvarname="V7")
```

Contents of test.sasdata:

```
1,TRUE
2,FALSE
3,TRUE
```

Output from SAS when I run "test.sas":

```
NOTE: Invalid data for boolean in line 1 3-6
RULE: ----+----1--...
1     1,TRUE 6
id=1 boolean=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
... (errors for remaining rows)
```

The workaround is to do:

```
df$boolean <- as.numeric(df$boolean)
```

before export. Or, more generically:

```
logicals <- sapply(df, is.logical)
if (any(logicals))
    df[logicals] <- lapply(df[logicals], as.numeric)
```

Am I doing something wrong with write.foreign?  Or is this a bug?

**EDIT:** Revised code above to use sapply/lapply as writeForeignSAS does.  I have [submitted a patch to writeForeignSAS](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-September/062036.html) which incorporates the above.

Thanks to DWin for his assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that 'logical' is not listed among the classes that are claimed to be properly exported to SAS, you could hardly call it a bug.

```
?write.foreign
```

Comment: I reviewed that before posting, and as the doc does not explicitly address logical, I thought that implied that it was supported since logical is a base type of R.

Comment: You are advised to ask the maintainer or the author for feature requests or bug reports. Perhaps Lumley or Weigand will accept a suggestion to modify the `writeForeignSAS` function, but at the moment I see no provisions for testing "logical" mode in the code I searched. The maintainer is R-Core so a letter to r-devel would be needed. I would not file a bug report, since it really "unexpected behavior" rather than something that is documented to be wrong.